# Create Excel Function to Load Part of an HTML File Into a Single Cell?

Tags: html, excel, vba, macos

**Background**
Everyday, I upload hundreds of products into our database, each product contains a "Short Description", "Full Description", and "Meta Description". I write these in an HTML template I built, and historically, I would just copy and paste each section of description to their corresponding cells. However, recently I've determined that it could be potentially faster to save each 'description'.html file (for reuse) and program an Excel function to pull the necessary data from the description file.

I'm using Excel on Mac, and I'm pretty new to VBA.

**Here is what I'd like to accomplish:** Create a function that loads HTML content from a local file into an individual cell, and use a function parameter to determine what part of the html should be loaded into the cell.
[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

First, I'm trying to 'just' get the html data into 'one' cell.
Next, I need to separate the data by either 'short', 'long', or 'meta' description.

Thus far, I'm stuck on just getting the html in the cell via VBA.

**Here's my function:**

```
Function Description(InputFile, Part As String)

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim DescPart As String
    
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    URL = InputFile
    DescPart = Part
    
    With IE
        .navigate URL
        .Visible = False
        
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        
        Set HTMLDoc = .document
    End With
    
    Select Case DescPart
        Case Short 'Get Short Description (Future)
            Description = HTMLDoc
        Case Full 'Get Full Description (Future)
            Description = HTMLDoc
        Case Meta 'Get Meta Description (Future)
            Description = HTMLDoc
    End Select
End Function
```

I've read a lot about using VBA to read HTML (I don't understand most of it). The code above is more-or-less developed off of my research. I'm pretty sure that the traditional route of using 'Internet Explorer' won't work since this is built on Mac (I could be wrong). Would I need an AppleScript to scrape the HTML? All of the material I have found is for VBA on Windows.

---

This might work on Mac, but I'm still running into an error... (The "HTMLDocument" type is not defined) Because Mac doesn't allow Active-x controls?

```
Function Description(InputFile, Part As String)

    Dim URL As String
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument, HTMLdoc2 As HTMLDocument
    Dim DescPart As String
    
    URL = InputFile
    DescPart = Part
    
    Set HTMLdoc2 = New HTMLDocument
    Set HTMLdoc = HTMLdoc2.createDocumentFromURL(URL, "")
    
    While HTMLdoc.readyState <> "complete"
        DoEvents
    Wend
    
    Select Case DescPart
        Case Short
            Description = HTMLdoc
        Case Full
            Description = HTMLdoc
        Case Meta
            Description = HTMLdoc
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: AFAIK you don't have Microsoft HTML Object Library on Mac ergo no MHSHTML.HTMLDocument ergo no HTMLDocument

Comment: I would switch languages on a mac and use something like python and work with csvs.

Comment: @QHarr so, use Python in place of VBA? Do you know of any documentation or resources on using Python with VBA? Also, what do you mean by "work with csvs"?

Comment: I wouldn't involve VBA at all if going down Python route. However, there are several Excel python add-ins around e.g. xlwings that might be ok? Work with csvs means have python read/write to csv and read/write to/from databases. Depending what you want there are faster routes than python but python is pretty simple.